# Unbalanced calls to UIViewController when asking for HealthKit permissions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, healthkit

I ask my user for permission to HealthKit by allowing the user to click a button 'Connect to Health App'.

This calls the     [HKStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:...] function which will ultimately present a view controller modally for the user to configure the various permissions.

Doing this leads to the error "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UIViewController:"

I have tried using [performSelector withDelay] in the event handler of the button to a separate function which then in turn calls HealthKit ie. in order to allow the button pressing animation to complete before a new view controller is pushed onto screen. The error persists.

Any ideas or is this a bug or is the warning harmless?

Thanks

Comment: I have same warning. Apple says my app crashes on the startup, I wouldn't ignore this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in iOS, not your application.  It's also harmless, so don't worry about it.

Comment: Just to clarify, this issue is not going to affect the app in any way?